# Erro statement e executeUpdate SQL - NetBeans

Tags: java, sql, netbeans, jdbc

```
try{
      Class.forName(driver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(str_conn, usuario, senha);
      Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
      String sqlinsert ="insert into cheque (data_cheque,valor,repasse) values ("+
        jTextField1.getText()+","+
        jTextField2.getText()+",' "+
        jTextField3.getText()+" ') ";
      stmt.executeUpdate(sqlinsert);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Sucesso");
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Não foi possível carregar o driver.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Problema com o SQL");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: O que você quer perguntar?

Comment: Estou com erro na linha "Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();" e "stmt.executeUpdate(sqlinsert);" @PauloHDSousa

Comment: @RaphaelSantos Edite sua pergunta e adicione essas informações. Adicione também qual é o erro que você recebe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acredito o erro seja uma `query sql` mal formatada, valores que não são números devem estar entre aspas simples. Para utilizar *prepared statements* troque os valores que estão na consulta por interrogações, e passe os valores através das funções `PreparedStatement.set*(index, value)`, onde o `*` é o tipo de dado a ser trocado.

Sua *query* sql com os valores seria imprimida assim:

```
insert into cheque (data_cheque,valor,repasse) values (2015-01-30, 100, 300')
```

Se fosse aplica-la direto no banco deveria escapar os valores não numericos com aspas, desse jeito:

```
insert into cheque (data_cheque,valor,repasse) values ('2015-01-30', 100, 300)
```

Com o *prepared statement* você evita o sql injection, *tipa* as entradas do usuário e também não precisa se preocupar em escapar os valores.

```
 String sqlinsert ="insert into cheque (data_cheque,valor,repasse) values (?,?,?) ";
 PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlinsert); 

 stmt.setDate(1,  jTextField1.getText());
 stmt.setInt(2,  jTextField1.getText());
 stmt.setInt(3,  jTextField1.getText());

 stmt.executeUpdate(sqlinsert);
```

[Lista dos setters correspondentes ao tipo - Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)